# Simplest Way to Serve Jupyter Incubator Dashboards Locally

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've been exploring steps one and two from the Jupyter Incubator Dashboards project (more information here: https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/dashboards/wiki). Its simple to turn my notebooks into usable dashboards, which is just great.

My problem is that I'm unsure about step three, which is sharing/hosting the dashboards. I'm in an enterprise environment with a local server. I need to be able to share the dashboards on the local server and then have people access them over the web. Essentially, I need the "deploy as a local dashboard" option from step two (dashboards_bundlers). It seems that this functionality is now deprecated, however.

My question is this, is there a simple way to share dashboards locally here? I've been looking at the dashboards_server application, but it looks a little over my head right now. The functionality here looks powerful, but is probably more than what we need for the time being.

If this is the only option then I will proceed there, but I wanted to see if anyone has a simpler solution first.

Answer (score 1):

As I see you have posted the similar question on the [Github Issues section of Jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/dashboards_server/issues/308)

You have received the answer too but is not satisfactory I guess. As the person have mentioned that there isn't any way right now for achieving what you are expecting.
But if you want that others should access the local copy of your system Jupyter Dashboard then it is better you make your system as server itself. Then you can grant access to the people for viewing your server/local machine. Others can be a child like systems for your local system.

Just like a Parent-child or Say Master-slave would allow others to have access to your Jupyter DashBoard Copy.

It might be a bit confusing but this is way you can achieve whaht you have mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a too simplistic answer. Our company uses Windows 7 enterprise. I have Jupyter Notebook running on a desktop which I access by running the command:

`jupyter.exe notebook --ip=10.106.166.180 --no-browser`

I just use the IP address of my host computer.

Then I just send people the ipynb url

example http://10.106.166.180:8888/notebooks/Notebooks/sample.ipynb

As long as you don't mind people tinkering, using or snooping around your notebooks. Also if the time comes, you can always restart the server then add a password so that people can't access it anymore.

Comment: This looks good. I am going to test and respond back before the end of the day.

Comment: Good luck, some people in my department also want to learn basic python but do not want the hassle of installing python or having clutter in their PC. So I share them the notebook and just ask them to rename to there own names so the can experiment.

Comment: I was curious about jupyter dashboard so I tried it out, for any notebook you have just add `?dashboard` at the end of the url and this will put the notebook in dashboard preview mode. so when you share your url they will automatically see the dashboard view http://10.106.166.180:8888/notebooks/Notebooks/sample.ipynb`?dashboard'